# Counting the number of times a character occurs in a very large text file

Tags: php

I would like to count the occurrence of all commas in a very large text file (its has comma delimited data). Size is 28mb. I thought of loading up the text file and doing something like this:

```
substr_count($text, ',');
```

Good idea? Will it work?

The overall task is to find out how many rows of data it has. When I count the number of commas, I will divide this by the number of columns which will give me the number of rows. If there is a better way of doing this, let me know!

Thanks all

### EDIT

The below worked but is it efficient as the suggestions?

```
$lines = file('C:\wamp\CE.txt');

$number = 0;

foreach($lines as $line){

   $number = $number + substr_count($line, ',');

}

echo $number;
```

Comment: But are you looking for rows or columns? Or is your file format very specific, all in one line and you only have commas separating the values? CSV format generally translates into a table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSV goes like this:

**lines** -> rows

**commas** -> columns

So you got it wrong on the rows. If you want to count the rows just iterate the file for newlines.

```
$file = "youfile.txt"; 
$lines = count(file($file)); 
echo "There are ".$lines." lines in ".$file;
```

Would work as an example...

Comment: This actually gives number of lines and not number of ",", my text file must not have newlines!!

Comment: So are you saying that the result of the above code on your file is 1? Maybe what you have is a very big line with some commas separating values, but not a CSV file. Does that better describe the situation?

Answer (score 1):

If your records are separated by new lines, you could do the following to get the number of rows:

```
  $file = "input.csv";
  $rows = count(file($file));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Good idea? Will it work?

Have you tried it? That should tell a lot.

Basically, since `substr_count` is an intrinsic that does exactly what you want, it will very probably offer optimal performance.

If you find performance to be too bad, you might need to load the file in pieces, though.

Answer (score 0):

Frankie is right in his answer. Hoever, I'd suggest reading the file with the file() function and then simply counting the array elements.

Comment: How is that any different from Frankie’s answer?

Comment: Well, when I wrote it, he hadn't added the call to file() yet.